# How to restrict Workstation access to specific Domain Users

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I would like to know how to restrict user access from logging into workstations, servers, etc.

I was wondering if there were specific machine settings in Active Directory that could be set. Ideally it would be most beneficial to set security groups to have access to specific machines, with no access unless specific added. Thanks!

Comment: There is clearly no research done here.

Answer (score 2):

In Active Directory Users and Computers, right click the user you want to limit to specific machines, and click properties. Under the 'Account' tab, click 'Log On to...'. Click the radial next to the 'Following Computers' and select which computers they can login with.